# How can I set NODE_ENV=production with nodemon on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, nodemon

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=staging && nodemon app",
    "production": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon app",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

it's not working ⚒

my staging port is 3000 and my production port is 5000 but no matter what I do nodemon is not taking the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The likely problem is that **the space character before `&&` becomes part of the environment-variable values**, so that the values are `staging`  and `production`  - note the trailing space - rather than `staging` and `production`.

The simplest way to avoid this is to *remove the space before `&&`* (it looks awkward, but it works):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=staging&& nodemon app",
    "production": "set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon app",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

To avoid such problems **in general, it's best to assign variable values in `cmd.exe` using the form

`set "variable=value"`**, i.e. to enclose the name, the `=`, and the value in `"..."` overall, which delimits the value explicitly, irrespective of subsequent (unquoted) whitespace; therefore, the following should work too (with the embedded `"` characters escaped as `\"`, as required by JSON).

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET \"NODE_ENV=staging\" && nodemon app",
    "production": "set \"NODE_ENV=production\" && nodemon app",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Comment: `"production": "set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon app"`
 **It works** ( btw I'm using Powershell )

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SabbirHasan. That you're using PowerShell is incidental here, because what matters is the shell that `npm` uses when scripts are invoked, which is `cmd.exe`  by default, and your script definitions indeed use `cmd.exe` syntax.

Comment: should I switch to Linux for big node project?

Comment: @SabbirHasan, not necessarily, but if you want your `package.json` files to _also_ work on Unix-like platforms as-is, switching to use of WSL on Windows may help. However, this is a bigger discussion than can fit in a comments exchange here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but, environment variables can be set before running app with nodemon like this without using the `set name=value` method

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=staging nodemon app",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon app",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, without "set", for example `NODE_ENV=development nodemon app.js`

Comment: This duplicates what was suggested earlier and has little detail.  This response looks better if it was a comment on an existing response.  if you had more detail I would have put it though, though as its own answer.